# SQL Group percentage calculation using windowing functions

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, window-functions

Trying to convert a row-by-row percentage calculation query to dynamic by using window function over a partition by column. Not sure this is the right way please suggest.

```
create table qdetails
(
    qcode int, 
    qcode_detail_01 int, 
    qcode_detail_02 int
);

insert into qdetails(qcode, qcode_detail_01, qcode_detail_02) 
values (25, 999, 56),
       (95, 999, 67),
       (96, 999, 68),
       (21, 888, 56),
       (22, 888, 67),
       (26, 888, 68);

create table qmaster
(
     qcode int, 
     qtype text,  
     qvalue int
);

insert into qmaster (qcode, qtype, qvalue) 
values
(25, 'XYZ', 25),
(95, 'XYZ', 34),
(96, 'XYZ', 17),
(99, 'XYZ', 6),
(91, 'XYZ', 4),
(92, 'XYZ', 14),
(21, 'ABC', 7),
(22, 'ABC', 23),
(23, 'ABC', 11),
(24, 'ABC', 6),
(24, 'ABC', 4),
(26, 'ABC', 14);
```

For these table structures I have the following code; I'm trying to do this in a single query without repeating this for each row. This is on SQLite but that should not matter.

```
select
    a.qcode_detail_01,
    b.qtype,
    a.qcode,
    b.qvalue,
    /* calculating % for one qtype at a time manually*/
    sum(cast(b.qvalue as float))/(select sum(cast(b.qvalue as float)) from qmaster b where b.qtype = "XYZ") as 'Percentage'
from 
    qdetails a,
    qmaster b
where 
    b.qtype = "XYZ"
    and a.qcode = b.qcode
group by 
    a.qcode, a.qcode_detail_01;

/*repeat for ABC*/
select
    a.qcode_detail_01,
    b.qtype,
    a.qcode,
    b.qvalue,
    /* calculating % for one qtype at a time manually*/ 
    sum(cast(b.qvalue as float))/(select sum(cast(b.qvalue as float)) from qmaster b where b.qtype = "ABC") as 'Percentage'
from 
    qdetails a,
    qmaster b
where 
    b.qtype = "ABC"
    and a.qcode = b.qcode
group by 
    a.qcode, a.qcode_detail_01;
```

The part that is not working is this:

```
/*Avoid Repetition by doing this dynamically using Window Function */
select
a.qcode_detail_01,
b.qtype,
a.qcode,
b.qvalue,
cast(b.qvalue as float)/sum(cast(b.qvalue as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY b.qtype)  as 'Percentage'
from qdetails a,
qmaster b
and a.qcode = b.qcode
group by a.qcode,a.qcode_detail_01;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/309c92/2) for the same; please advise.
For the sample data above, i'm looking to get the following result with a single query

```
qcode_detail_01 qtype   qcode   qvalue  Percentage
999 XYZ 25  25  0.25
999 XYZ 95  34  0.34
999 XYZ 96  17  0.17
888 ABC 21  7   0.1076923076923077
888 ABC 22  23  0.35384615384615387
888 ABC 26  14  0.2153846153846154
```

Comment: "not working" how?

Comment: Please only tag the **single** rdbms you are using because it matters a lot - every rdbms had it's own custom dialect.

Comment: Please provide sample date and desired results do we can understand your gaol.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to join a CTE that returns the total values for each `qtype`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT qtype, SUM(qvalue) total_value FROM qmaster GROUP BY qtype)
SELECT d.qcode_detail_01, m.qtype, d.qcode, m.qvalue,
       SUM(CAST(m.qvalue AS FLOAT)) / c.total_value Percentage
FROM qdetails d 
INNER JOIN qmaster m ON d.qcode = m.qcode
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.qtype = m.qtype
GROUP BY d.qcode, d.qcode_detail_01, m.qtype
ORDER BY d.qcode_detail_01;
```

Another way to do it, with a `LEFT` join and window function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.qcode_detail_01, m.qtype, d.qcode, m.qvalue,
         SUM(CAST(m.qvalue AS FLOAT)) / 
         SUM(SUM(CAST(m.qvalue AS FLOAT))) OVER (PARTITION BY m.qtype) AS Percentage
  FROM qmaster m LEFT JOIN qdetails d
  ON d.qcode = m.qcode
  GROUP BY m.qcode, d.qcode_detail_01, m.qtype
)
WHERE qcode_detail_01 IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aa726eddce0c1e8dad9d3f9c8aa36808).

Also, use proper joins with `ON` clauses.